# Switch statement using a selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

How do to all,

This is the first time posting on the site, so i presume i have not followed all the
formats and protocols correctly.

My app has a UIView containing a list of questions, and a UISegmentedControl called "question_btn" for each question. The UISegmentedControl has 2 segments, the first for a NO answer, the 2nd for a YES answer, corresponding to each question.

Each "question_btn" individually calls -(void) processQuestions{}, but when i click on each "question_btn" only the last one is processed properly. All previous "question_btns" call the processQuestions method, but do not implement its code.

Im my problem with the UISegmentControl, or the switch statement, or both.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The button is defined as follows

```
 question_btn  = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(QUESTION_BUTTON_XPOS, questionsButton_YPos, 80, 20)] autorelease]; 
 [question_btn insertSegmentWithTitle:@"No" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
 [question_btn insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Yes" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
 [question_btn setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
 [question_btn setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
 question_btn.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
 question_btn.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
 [question_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(processQuestions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Below is the processQuestions

```
- (void) processQuestions
{
 //NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: Called");
 //Process the questions i.e. determine whether yes or no was the answer

     answersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

     int selectedIndex; 

     selectedIndex = [question_btn selectedSegmentIndex];

     switch (selectedIndex)
     {
         case 0:

             NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: No answered");    

             break;

         case 1:    

             NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: Yes answered");    

             break;  
     } 

     [answersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedIndex]];

     NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: answersArray contains: %@",  answersArray);
}
```

Here is how i got the code to iterate properly and get the question_btn selected index value. It was just a matter of creating a mutable array to hold the question_btn objects,
and then set the selected index value for each button using a for loop.
The buttonsArray is set in my createView method.

```
buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (void) processQuestions
```

{
    //NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: Called");

```
answersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];           

int selectedIndex;

for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i ++)
{   
    question_btn = (UISegmentedControl*)[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];     

    selectedIndex = [question_btn selectedSegmentIndex];

    switch (selectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:

            NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: No answered for question: %d", i + 1);              

            break;

        case 1:             

            NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: Yes answered for question: %d", i + 1);     


            break;      
    }   

    [answersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedIndex]];
}
    NSLog(@"QuestionsView processQuestions: answersArray contains: %@", answersArray);
```

}

Comment: Can you reindent your code properly ?

Comment: All the segmented controls are added to the same view?  How do you know which question the processQuestions method is being called for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of questions, you can use an array of Segemnted control. You may have a button, 'Get Result' so when pressed, you iterate through all the segmented controls and check there selected index (yes/no - 0/1).

right now, in your above code, processQuestions is called for each segmented control's state changing. If the default value is kept by the user, it will not add result to the answer array.

Comment: Hello karim, i am not sure what you mean when you say " if the default value is kept by the user".

Comment: [question_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(processQuestions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; So processQuestions will be called only when the user tap on the segment control. what if the user do not tap, and regard the default selected index denote the right answer?